Faster evaluation of matrix operation
I am working on a code to simulate spins under certain condition. The code runs but takes abnormally long time. earlier I asked  similar question but this is more complex and fails the earlier procedure. I understand that propX and propY are taking long to evaluate but I can not modify it. What am I missing?  Please suggest something to improve the computation process so that it can be run faster or has there any other way to re-write the entire script to run faster? Following is my code:
iniMat = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, -(1/2)}};
A = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    1/2}};
Bx = {{0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 
    1/2, 0}};
By = {{0, -(I/2), -(I/2), 0}, {I/2, 0, 0, -(I/2)}, {I/2, 0, 
    0, -(I/2)}, {0, I/2, I/2, 0}};
detC = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, -(1/2)}};
\[Omega]D = 2 \[Pi] 1;  \[Omega]CS = 2 \[Pi] 2; \[Omega]r = 
 2 \[Pi] 5; \[Omega]H = 2 \[Pi] 5; \[Omega]X = 2 \[Pi] 2; \[Omega]rf =
  2 \[Pi] 3; 
\[Tau]p = Pi/\[Omega]rf; \[Tau]r = (2 \[Pi])/\[Omega]r;
points = Table[i, {i, 0, Pi/\[Omega]rf, 0.01 Pi/\[Omega]rf}];
Selectedangle = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}, {j, 0, 
     2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}], 1];

\[Omega]Dt[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := \[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
       2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]) ; 

propX[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot @@ ParallelTable[
    N@MatrixExp[-I Integrate[(A \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] + 
          Bx \[Omega]rf), {t, points[[i]], points[[i + 1]]}]], {i, 1, 
     Length@points - 1}];
propY[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot @@ ParallelTable[
    N@MatrixExp[-I Integrate[(A \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] + 
          By \[Omega]rf), {t, points[[i]], points[[i + 1]]}]], {i, 1, 
     Length@points - 1}];
propDP[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  MatrixExp[-I A Integrate[\[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], {t, 
      0, \[Tau]r - \[Tau]p}]];
prop[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, nblock_] := 
  MatrixPower[
   propY[\[Beta], \[Gamma]].propDP[\[Beta], \[Gamma]].propX[\[Beta], \
\[Gamma]].propDP[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], nblock];
finMat[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, nblock_] := 
  prop[\[Beta], \[Gamma], 
    nblock].iniMat.prop[\[Beta], \[Gamma], 
     nblock]\[ConjugateTranspose];
sig[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, nblock_] := 
  Tr[detC\[ConjugateTranspose].finMat[\[Beta], \[Gamma], nblock]];
sigmap[n_] := Total@Map[sig[#[[1]], #[[2]], n] &, Selectedangle];
output = Table[sigmap[n], {n, 1, 750}];


You compute the matrix exponentials in exact arithmetic and convert to floating point precision afterwards. My suggestion: Do the conversion before the MatrixExp.

Also, it should suffice to compute the integral symbolically once. Use something like F[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, a_,     b_] = -I Integrate[(A \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] +        Bx \[Omega]rf), {t, a, b}]; and then propX[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] :=    Dot @@ ParallelTable[     MatrixExp[      N@F[\[Beta], \[Gamma], points[[i]], points[[i + 1]]]], {i, 1,       Length@points - 1}];.

@HenrikSchumacher I was trying your suggestion, but that did not improve the computation significantly in my machine.

Essentially, your code is a double loop: the outer loop goes over n (with a trip count of 750) and the inner loop goes over the list Selectedangle. This is why you compute all the matrices propX, propY, prop 750 times. I suggest to swap inner and outer loop.

Essentially, your code is a double loop: the outer loop goes over n (with a trip count of 750) and the inner loop goes over the list Selectedangle. This is why you compute all the matrices propX, propY, prop 750 times. I suggest to swap inner and outer loop.
Below is the code that I created this morning. It contains also many other tweaks, e.g., to enforce that all matrices are packed (which requires that they all use the same floating point type -- Complex in this case).
Moreover, I compiled the loop over n into the CompiledFunction cf.
iniMat = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, -(1/2)}} + 0. I;
A = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}} + 0. I;
Bx = {{0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}} + 0. I;
By = {{0, -(I/2), -(I/2), 0}, {I/2, 0, 0, -(I/2)}, {I/2, 0, 0, -(I/2)}, {0, I/2, I/2, 0}} + 0. I;
detC = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -(1/2)}} + 0. I;

\[Omega]D = 2 \[Pi] 1.; \[Omega]CS = 2 \[Pi] 2.; \[Omega]r = 
 2 \[Pi] 5.; \[Omega]H = 2 \[Pi] 5.; \[Omega]X = 
 2 \[Pi] 2.; \[Omega]rf = 2 \[Pi] 3.;
\[Tau]p = Pi/\[Omega]rf; \[Tau]r = (2 \[Pi])/\[Omega]r;

points = Subdivide[0., Pi/\[Omega]rf, 100];
Selectedangle = 
  Tuples[{Subdivide[0., Pi, 50], Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 100]}];

Block[{a, b, \[Beta], \[Gamma], t},
  \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := \[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
        2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
        2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]);
  
  F[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, a_, 
    b_] = -I Integrate[(A \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] + 
       Bx \[Omega]rf), {t, a, b}];
  G[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, a_, 
    b_] = -I Integrate[(A \[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] + 
       By \[Omega]rf), {t, a, b}];
  H[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = -I A Integrate[\[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \
\[Gamma]], {t, 0, \[Tau]r - \[Tau]p}];
  ];

propX[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot @@ Table[
    MatrixExp[F[\[Beta], \[Gamma], points[[i]], points[[i + 1]]]], {i,
      1, Length@points - 1}];
propY[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot @@ Table[
    MatrixExp[G[\[Beta], \[Gamma], points[[i]], points[[i + 1]]]], {i,
      1, Length@points - 1}];
propDP[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := MatrixExp[H[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]];

p0 = IdentityMatrix[4, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision] + 0. I;
detCHvec = Flatten[detC\[ConjugateTranspose]];

cf = Compile[{{p0, _Complex, 2}, {m, _Complex, 
     2}, {detCHvec, _Complex, 1}, {iniMat, _Complex, 
     2}, {nmax, _Integer}},
   Block[{p, result},
    p = p0;
    Table[p = p . m; 
     detCHvec . Flatten[p . iniMat . p\[ConjugateTranspose]], {n, 1, 
      nmax}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

This is how I run it:
output = Sum[
   {\[Beta], \[Gamma]} = Selectedangle[[k]];
   a = propY[\[Beta], \[Gamma]];
   b = propDP[\[Beta], \[Gamma]];
   c = propX[\[Beta], \[Gamma]];
   m = a . b . c . b;
   cf[p0, m, detCHvec, iniMat, 750]
   ,
   {k, 1, Length[Selectedangle]}
   ];

On my machine, this takes about 35 sec. That's just a fraction of the runtime of sigmap for a single n. (Actually, I could not be bother to wait for sigmap[1] to finish.) So I guess, this is several thousand times faster than the original code.
Also note that I removed ParallelTable. One should use parallelization only in the most outer loop construct, because launching the jobs always has some overhead. (So one might want to replace Sum by ParallelSum in my code. However, I have not invested the time to make this run properly. One would have to distribute all definitions to the parallel kernels, I guess.) Interestingly, Mathematica seems to use all CPU cores for this computation anyway; I just cannot figure out why this is. (And I've got the hunch that this makes my code much slower than it could be...)
Disclaimer: Because I could not wait for your code to terminate, I was not able to check whether my code does the right thing. Use it at your own risk.

Amazing!! That works absolutely fine and it is many thousand times faster. That has solved my problem. Thank you so muchhh..... I am really excited to know about the compiled function and the way you sum up.

You're welcome! =)
